# SCRIPT87: Invalid argument In IE8 Using HighCharts v3.0.5

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

Using the source version of highcharts I see that I get this error on:

> highcharts.src.js, line 5099 character 4

This is in the `var VMLRendererExtension` block:

```
init: function (container, width, height) {
        var renderer = this,
            boxWrapper,
            box;

        renderer.alignedObjects = [];

        boxWrapper = renderer.createElement(DIV);
        box = boxWrapper.element;
        box.style.position = RELATIVE; // for freeform drawing using renderer directly
        container.appendChild(boxWrapper.element);


        // generate the containing box
        renderer.isVML = true;
        renderer.box = box;
        renderer.boxWrapper = boxWrapper;


        renderer.setSize(width, height, false);

        // The only way to make IE6 and IE7 print is to use a global namespace. However,
        // with IE8 the only way to make the dynamic shapes visible in screen and print mode
        // seems to be to add the xmlns attribute and the behaviour style inline.
        if (!doc.namespaces.hcv) {

            doc.namespaces.add('hcv', 'urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml');

            // setup default css
            doc.createStyleSheet().cssText =
                'hcv\\:fill, hcv\\:path, hcv\\:shape, hcv\\:stroke' +
                '{ behavior:url(#default#VML); display: inline-block; } ';

        }
    }
```

The error is on the `doc.createStyleSheet().cssText` item. Not sure which part of it is dieing.

We have two charts on our page. A main data chart and one that does a distribution of data across areas. If I only show one or the other chart (meaning do not even render one chart) on the page I do not get this error. If both charts are rendered I get the first chart in execution order but not the second. Our chart code can be found [here](http://jsfiddle.net/wergeld/Cvv8t/show/). Note that I am not able to reproduce this error on the jsFiddle. This error only occurs in IE8.

I have seen this [post](http://forum.highcharts.com/highstock-usage/highcharts-ie7-8-error-t17393/) on the HighCharts forum. I am not able to change the document type as my code is just a small piece of the larger site. The only way to not show the error is to comment out his `doc.createStyleSheet().cssText` line. I would rather not just comment this out.

Now, this is where it gets ugly. This only happens on this one page. If we go to any other page that displays data I do not get this error. So what, you say. Well, the chart builder code is identical on every page. The only differences are the series (categories and values) and the height of the chart. We increase the height of the chart dynamically based on how many series we have to make the text easier to read. I have tested various numbers of categories in the distribution graph for this data set that does not throw this error. If I go to other pages and try and match the height of the chart on the failing page I also cannot reproduce this error.

Comment: I opened this (http://jsfiddle.net/wergeld/Cvv8t/show/) exmaple in IE8, and errors don't appear, so how can I reprodeuce this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Compare the following items between the working and non-working pages:

- The doctypes
- The script tags
- The meta tags